# Android Mediaplayer not working on Android 2.3

Tags: video, stream, android-mediaplayer, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm trying to realize a video stream in my app. Therefore I use Android's Mediaplayer and on Android 4.0 everything works really nice. Now I test my app on an 2.3.3 device an get following error output in the logcat:

**de.package.name.MediaPlayer   error (1, -19)**

**de.package.name.MediaPlayer   Error (1,-19)**

My surfaceCreated-Method looks like the following:

```
try {
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);    

            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(r.getImageUrl());                                
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

r.getImageUrl() is the link to the stream, something like this http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4

In the following you'll see the implementation of the onPrepared-Method

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mMediaPlayer.start();
    Log.d("debug", "Called after start"); //Is printed in LogCat
}
```

As said before, at Android 4.0 everything works well, but on 2.3.3 no Video is displayed and I get the above error output. I've tried to google this error, but every possible solution I found, did not help. 
Is any body here, who also dealed with the problem or has an idea how to get rid of this problem?

Thanks for any help in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after one more hour of search I'm finally able to solve the problem. I've looked at the example implementation of media player from google ([link](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html)) and implemented my mediaplayer the same way google does. I dont know, where my mistake was, but finally it also works on Android 2.3.3 :)